# Network program without "Windows Security Alert"

Tags: c, windows, winapi, networking

I've been trying to read up on Networking in C or rather, networking in general. I already made a few Client/Server Tests but there's just one issue I can't seem to get around. It's not really an issue I guess but I am not really able to test my program and see if it even works because of it.

Whenever I run my program locally, that is, if the client connects to localhost, the program works fine, but if I were to run the client on a different computer connected to the same network, it does not. The reason is obviously the Windows Firewall blocking my program (which, frankly, I wouldn't blame since it **IS** doing its job which is to block applications that aren't certified). When I start my server application, I get the typical "Windows Security Alert" box as I should...

[image: Windows Security Alert]

But the thing is, I don't actually own this computer and the group policy obviously prevents me from "allowing access" or modifying the firewall settings in any way. So I am unable to see if my program even works. Is it possible to make a program (preferably in C) without needing to allow it access through the firewall? Is there a way to make windows trust my program, do I need to certify it? If I were to publish a program like this, I would like my users to be able to run the program "right out of the box" without seeing a "scary" windows security alert box.

A lot of applications, I've noticed, are automatically trusted and accepted by the firewall right after downloading. Why is that?

I don't think my source code would be at all that useful, but in case you need it, I simply used Microsoft's simple Server/Client example.

[server code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winsock/complete-server-code)

[client code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winsock/complete-client-code)

Comment: Opening a port and listening/accepting to it results in a warning from a firewall. Any firewall would respond the same. For Windows, you can use the Filtering Platform to configure it programmatically.

Comment: The answer is fairly obvious. You need to configure the firewall to allow the traffic.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I am not able to do that, I did say that I don't own the computer

Comment: Then you are stuck. If you can't clear the firewall, you gotta give up.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan wow xD thanks, that's very motivational lol

Comment: Perhaps you can just ignore the firewall then and hope that it decides to let your program through

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A lot of applications, I've noticed, are automatically trusted and accepted by the firewall right after downloading. Why is that?

Many (most?) applications that require network access ask the user during install if the installer should create a firewall exception for the program. As installers run with elevated privileges they can do that.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't very considerate for specifics when I was asking the question, but does this popup only show with LAN connections, or at least when trying to run a server? Because the applications I am talking about are part of a WAN.

Comment: AFAIK you get that for all connections that aren't local.

Comment: Well this program specifically is local. I've tried my server/client on a VM using a different computer entirely and it worked fine. When trying to run the server, the popup came up (obviously). But when trying to run the client, it did not request for anything (which is fine by me).

When I try it on my laptop (which is what I was using before) nothing works. I think my administration might be blocking LAN connections. I've tried using the `ping` command using `cmd.exe` to ping any private IP on my network but it can't seem to find any.